# How to let dash app run custom javascript code?

Tags: javascript, python, plotly-dash

I have go over through [this doc](https://dash.plotly.com/external-resources) but is still confused with how Dash executes custom javascript. I have made an example with some attempts. The idea is to create a simple calculator, but keep calculating logic in custom javascript:

app.py

```
import dash
from dash import html, dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        html.H1("Simple Calculator"),
        html.Div(
            children=[
                html.Div("Enter a number:"),
                dcc.Input(id="input-1", type="number", value=0),
            ]
        ),
        html.Div(
            children=[
                html.Div("Enter another number:"),
                dcc.Input(id="input-2", type="number", value=0),
            ]
        ),
        html.Button("Add", id="add-button", n_clicks=0),
        html.Button("Subtract", id="subtract-button", n_clicks=0),
        html.Div(id="result"),
        dcc.Store(id="result-store"),
        html.Script(src="calculator_logic.js"),
    ]
)


@app.callback(
    Output("result-store", "data"),
    [Input("add-button", "n_clicks"), Input("subtract-button", "n_clicks")],
    [State("input-1", "value"), State("input-2", "value")],
)
def calculate_result(add_clicks, subtract_clicks, input1, input2):
    operation = ""
    if add_clicks > 0:
        operation = "add"
    elif subtract_clicks > 0:
        operation = "subtract"

    result = 0
    if operation == "add":
        result = float(input1) + float(input2)
    elif operation == "subtract":
        result = float(input1) - float(input2)

    return result


@app.callback(
    Output("result", "children"),
    [Input("result-store", "data")]
)
def display_result(result):
    if result is not None:
        script_html = "<script>document.getElementById('result').innerText = {result};</script>"
        return html.Div(children=[dcc.Markdown(script_html)])
    else:
        return ""


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

.\assets\custom-script.js

```
function calculateResult(operation, input1, input2) {
  if (operation === "add") {
    return input1 + input2;
  } else if (operation === "subtract") {
    return input1 - input2;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

window.calculateResult = calculateResult;
```

The output view is something like:

```
Simple Calculator
Enter a number:
0
Enter another number:
0
AddSubtract
<script>document.getElementById('result').innerText = {result};</script>
```

code is not executed.

I would like to understand if it is possible to let dash app run custom javascript function and if this is a good practice.

Comment: You can use [clientside-callbacks](https://dash.plotly.com/clientside-callbacks). They also have less overhead compared to regular callbacks.